# Error de IDENTITY_INSERT en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Mi problema es que intento hacer un simple insert en mi Base de Datos, pero al momento de ejecutar la sentencia me marca el siguiente error:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'tNacionalizacion'
>   can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT
>   is ON.

En mi insert tengo todos los campos con un respectivo valor.

Codigo del Insert

```
insert into tNacionalizacion values(140545,'2016-01-21',38,12,0,0,0,0,366,22,4741,'Ninguna',0,'MB014642','FGHFH5465','2015-01-08',12917,8,38,1,123384,'Descripcion',9,1,11202,75,75,6,1,56,68,0.000,'TL',0,0,NULL,2,'2017-03-29 13:27:23.650','2017-03-29 13:47:25.097',5479,'192.168.1.87',141300,4);
```

**Actualizacion**

Modifique el codigo de mi insert de la siguiente forma:

```
insert into tNacionalizacion(idPedimento,fecha,idCveDocEntrada,idTipoCambio,seguros,fletes,embalajes,otros,valorcomercial,valoraduana,observación,dta,prevalidacion,factura,cove,fechafactura,idproveedor,incoterm,idMoneda,factorMoneda,numParte,descripion,idTipoBien,secuencia,idFraccion,idPaisVendedor,idPaisOrigen,idUnidadComercial,cantidad,precioUnitario,idTasa,preferencia,idForpago,descargado,pedimentorectificado,idLayout,fechaIngreso,fechaActualizacion,idUsuario,ipActualizacion,descargo,idEmpresa) values(140545,'2016-01-21',38,12,0,0,0,0,366,22,4741,'Ninguna',0,'MB014642','FGHFH5465','2015-01-08',12917,8,38,1,123384,'Descripcion',9,1,11202,75,75,6,1,56,68,0.000,'TL',0,0,NULL,2,'2017-03-29 13:27:23.650','2017-03-29 13:47:25.097',5479,'192.168.1.87',141300,4);
```

y el error anterior se quito y se puso uno nuevo:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Pero en lo que a mi respecta los campos si coinciden.

Estructura de mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tNacionalizacion](
    [idNacionalizacion] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idPedimento] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fecha] [date] NOT NULL,
    [idCveDocEntrada] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idTipoCambio] [int] NOT NULL,
    [seguros] [float] NULL,
    [fletes] [float] NULL,
    [embalajes] [float] NULL,
    [otros] [float] NULL,
    [valorComercial] [float] NOT NULL,
    [valorAduana] [float] NOT NULL,
    [observación] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [dta] [float] NULL,
    [prevalidacion] [float] NOT NULL,
    [factura] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [cove] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [fechaFactura] [date] NOT NULL,
    [idProveedor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [incoterm] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [idMoneda] [int] NOT NULL,
    [factorMoneda] [float] NULL,
    [numParte] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [descripion] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [idTipoBien] [int] NOT NULL,
    [secuencia] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idFraccion] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idPaisVendedor] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idPaisOrigen] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idUnidadComercial] [int] NULL,
    [cantidad] [float] NOT NULL,
    [precioUnitario] [float] NOT NULL,
    [idTasa] [decimal](5, 3) NULL,
    [preferencia] [char](2) NULL,
    [idForPago] [int] NULL,
    [descargado] [int] NULL,
    [pedimentoRectificado] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [idLayout] [int] NULL,
    [fechaIngreso] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [fechaActualizacion] [datetime] NULL,
    [idUsuario] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ipActualizacion] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [descargo] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [idEmpresa] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__tNaciona__8EC33AF3797309D9] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idNacionalizacion] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Intenta añadiendo el nombre de las columnas  `insert into tNacionalizacion (column1,colum2...) values (.... )`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la definición de tu tabla para saber cuál es el campo es el que tiene la propiedad `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Con la [edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/59012/2) tienes un error sintáctico, claramente el error te indica que la cantidad de columnas que especificas no coincide con la cantidad de valores. Verificando tu sentencia, eso sucede.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el manejador de base de datos? ¿SQL Server, MySql, Oracle...?

Comment: @FLXTR estoy usando SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dice @Davlio en los comentarios, el número de columnas definidas en el `INSERT` no coinciden con el número de valores a insertar. Debes empatar una columna a un valor.

Respecto al primer error, se debe a que tienes una columna definida como `INDENTITY`, esto significa que los valores que se guarden ahí serán incrementales de forma automática y no se requiere que los definas en tu sentencia del `INSERT`, el manejador de base de datos hará este trabajo por ti.

Suponiendo que la columna `idPedimento` está definida como `IDENTITY` de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tNacionalizacion ](
    [idPedimento] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fecha] [datetime] NULL,
    [idCveDocEntrada] [int] NULL,
    --Aquí van todos los demás campos
CONSTRAINT [PK_tNacionalizacion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idPedimento] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Para realizar en `INSERT` no se debe especificar dicha columna:

```
INSERT INTO tNacionalizacion
(fecha, idCveDocEntrada, ...resto de las columnas)
VALUES 
('2016-01-21', 38, ...resto de las columnas)
```

Comment: seria la respuesta correcta solo que idpedimento no es autoincrementable solo idnacionalizacion y no esta dentro del insert

Comment: @David podrías generar el *script* del `CREATE TABLE...` con eso  podremos saber cuál es el que está causando el conflicto. Por cierto, del segundo error veo que tienes 42 columnas y 43 valores para realizar el `INSERT` Con la estructura que pusiste como imagen no dice cuál(es) son los campos IDENTITY

Comment: ya genere el script y entonces deja verifico que mis columnas coincidan

Comment: @David vale :) me avisas cualquier cosa